# Tmux Scroll Up/Down Page using Ctrl-b and Ctrl-f

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

Once in scroll-mode, how do I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to scroll up and down pages?

These commands currently move back and forth between characters.

*.tmux.conf*

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
setw -g xterm-keys on
set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
set -g history-limit 999999999

bind C-d detach
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf

set -g prefix C-z 

if-shell 'test "$(tmux -V)" = "tmux 1.5"' 'set -g prefix C-a,C-z'
if-shell 'test "$(tmux -V)" = "tmux 1.6"' 'set -g prefix2 C-a'
if-shell 'test "$(tmux -V)" = "tmux 1.7"' 'set -g prefix2 C-a'

unbind C-b 
bind C-a send-keys C-a 
bind C-z send-keys C-z 

# These are available in iTerm by default, but need to be explicitly configured
# in Terminal.app.
# S-Up:    ^[[1;2A
# S-Down:  ^[[1;2B
# S-Right: ^[[1;2C
# S-Left:  ^[[1;2D
bind -n S-Up copy-mode
bind -n S-Down command-prompt
bind -n S-Right next-window
bind -n S-Left previous-window

#set -g base-index 1

set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

Comment: Can you give a little more context? By default, 'ctrl-b' is the bind-key; ctrl-b,ctrl-b sends a literal ctrl-b to the program inside tmux. If this is running bash in emacs mode, you will go a character back (ctrl-b) or forward (ctrl-f).

Comment: Posted my .tmux.conf and I'm using iTerm

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add below into `.tmux.conf`, you can move like in vim use `hjkl`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>(PageDown/Up) in the tmux scroll mode. Even more, you can use `/` to search.

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g status-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-edit Up   history-up
bind-key -t vi-edit Down history-down
```

Hope this will help you :)